# Date time to string conversion

Tags: vb.net

I have to convert a string to date time...

String data is in this form: 13.6.2013. 8:06:36

The code:

```
Dim pDate As String
pDate = TextBox16.Text
Dim pro_Date As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(pDate, "DD.M.YYYY. hh24:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

And the error I get is: string was not recognized as a valid datetime

How to convert this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format string is case sensitive, so this does not work: "DD.M.YYYY". Also, 24h clock is uppercase `H` not "hh24". You need a single `H`  because `8:06:36` has no leading zero on the hour.

```
Dim pro_Date As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(pDate, "dd.M.yyyy. H:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

More informations acc. the ["H" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#H_Specifier)